# How to perform NAT hole punching on an additional client mid-session?

Tags: networking, udp, nat, hole-punching

I am working on a simple multiplayer game as an exercise to learn more about NAT hole punching.  I would like to support players joining mid-game, but I'm unsure how to handle that with NAT hole punching.

I have a (very rudimentary) working implementation of NAT hole punching that works with two clients, but once the hole is punched then the server is started on the host.  This leads to the issue where the host can't send the greeting to the new client because the port is already bound by the game server.  I can have the 3rd party rendezvous server keep track of the address and port that the host is using to send to the new client, but how would I issue a request to the new client from the host with the correct port to punch the hole to the host?

Thanks in advance!